# Did Ved Vyasa father children for his mother Satyavati?

Tags: vyasa

The wikipedia mentions the following about Vyasa.

> Vyasa is traditionally known as author of this epic and likewise
>   features as an important character in it. His mother Satyavati later
>   married King Shantanu of Hastinapura and had two sons, Chitrāngada and
>   Vichitravirya. Chitrangada died unmarried and Vichitravirya died
>   without issue, and hence their mother asked Vyasa to father the child
>   through the "Niyoga" method which specifies rules for appointing a
>   father to bear a child in case the husband is incapacitated or unable
>   to do so.

I have two questions based on the above information:

1) Does it mean that Satyavati, who is the mother of Ved Vyada, asked his own son to produce children for herself and king Shantanu?

2) Were Chitrangada and Vichitravirya, biological children of Satyavati and King Shantanu?

Comment: not for childeren herself ,she asked for grand son with amba & ambika wife of  Chitrangada and Vichitravirya  and your second point is right about Chitrangada and Vichitravirya, biological children of Satyadevi and King Shantanu

Answer (score 3):

> Satyavati bore Shantanu two sons: Chitrangada and Vichitravirya. The
>   Harivamsa tells of Bhishma recalling events after Shantanu's death.
>   During the period of mourning after Shantanu’s death, Ugrayudha
>   Paurava (usurper of the throne of Panchala) demanded that Bhishma hand
>   over Satyavati in return for wealth. Bhishma killed Ugrayudha Paurava,
>   who had lost his powers because he lusted after another's wife.
>   However, the Mahabharata does not include this event; it only
>   describes Bhishma crowning Chitrangada as king under Satyavati's
>   command. Chitrangada was later killed by a namesake gandharva (a
>   celestial musician).
>
> After Chitrangada's death his young brother Vichitravirya was crowned
>   king, while Bhishma ruled on his behalf (under Satyavati's command)
>   until Vichitravirya grew up. Vichitravirya married the princesses of
>   Kashi-Kosala: Ambika and Ambalika, who were won by Bhishma in a
>   Swayamvara (marriage choice). The childless Vichitravirya met with an
>   untimely death from tuberculosis.
>
> An aged Satyavati with her first born Vyasa With no heir to the
>   throne, Satyavati asked Bhishma to marry the widows of Vichitravirya
>   (following the practice of niyoga in its narrower sense, as a levirate
>   marriage) and rule as king. Bhishma refused, reminding Satyavati
>   of the promise he made to her father and his vow of
>   bachelorhood. He suggests that a Brahmin could be hired
>   to father children on the widows, thus preserving the dynasty.
>   Revealing to Bhishma the tale of her encounter with Parashara,
>   Satyavati well knew that this was the time to call her son Vyasa to
>   aid her. Satyavati coaxed Vyasa to have niyoga with his brother's
>   widows, saying: "from affection for thy brother Vichitravirya,
>   for the perpetuation of our dynasty, for the sake of this Bhishma's
>   request and my command, for kindness to all creatures, for the
>   protection of the people and from the liberality of thy heart, O
>   sinless one, it behooveth thee to do what I say." After convincing
>   Vyasa, Satyavati managed ( with great difficulty) to obtain the
>   consent of her "virtuous" daughters-in-law.[16] In the Mahabharata,
>   Vyasa agreed immediately to the niyoga. In the Devi Bhagavata Purana
>   version, Vyasa initially refused Satyavati's proposal. He argued that
>   Vichitravirya's wives were like his daughters; having niyoga with them
>   was a heinous sin, through which no good could come. As a master of
>   "realpolitik", the hungry-for-grandsons Satyavati asserted that to
>   preserve the dynasty, wrong directives by elders should be followed if
>   they are going to reduce the sorrow of a mother. Vyasa finally agreed
>   to that "disgusting task", but suggested that offspring of perversity
>   cannot be a source of joy.

**Birth of Pandu ,Dhritrashtra & vidhur your First point satyavati asked for her grand children not for herself**

> During the menstrual period of the older queen, Ambika, Satyavati
>   invited Vyasa to Ambika's bedchamber. However, during niyoga with
>   Vyasa, Ambika noticed his dark appearance and closed her eyes. Vyasa
>   declared to Satyavti that due to Ambika's cruelty, her son would be
>   blind (but strong) and have a hundred sons – later known as Kauravas
>   (descendants of Kuru). Satyavati considered such an heir to be an
>   unworthy king, so she asked Vyasa to have niyoga with her other
>   daughter-in-law. During their niyoga, Ambalika fell pale due to
>   Vyasa's grim appearance. As the result the child would be wan, Vyasa
>   told his mother, who begged for another child. In due course, the
>   blind Dhritarashtra and the pale Pandu were born. Satyavati again
>   invited Vyasa to Ambika's bedchamber; she remembered Vyasa's grim
>   appearance (and repulsive odour), and substituted a Shudra (lowest
>   caste) maid in her place. The maid respected the sage and was not
>   afraid of him, and Vyasa thus blessed her; her son would be the most
>   intelligent man, and she would no longer be a slave. Vyasa told
>   Satyavti of the deception, and then disappeared; Vidura, an
>   incarnation of the god Dharma, was born to the maid.

[Birth of children and grandchildren- Find Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyavati#Birth_of_children_and_grandchildren)

Comment: Good article. [Was Vidura incarnation of Yama or Dharma](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7039/1049)? What is the story of Ugrayudha?

Comment: @iammilind  i only find this link for Ugrayudha - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=z3ksBrWoZm0C&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=Ugrayudha+Paurava+of+panchal&source=bl&ots=uwoP1WZLTA&sig=iknpsj4evRHmUPws-U8rppYnJJo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMI46zWsayPyAIVgwqOCh0hBAHS#v=onepage&q=Ugrayudha%20Paurava%20of%20panchal&f=false

Comment: @iammilind http://www.manushi-india.org/pdfs_issues/PDF%20142/04%20panchakanya%20pg%2021-25.pdf find Ugrayudha in this pdf  also see this https://moralstories.wordpress.com/2006/09/24/dharmabalam/    and http://bachelorpledge.blogspot.in/2013/03/ugrayudha-paurava.html this all have same story mention in wiki of satyavati

Comment: “ During their niyoga, Ambalika fell pale due to Vyasa's grim appearance. As the result the child would be wan, Vyasa told his mother” <—— Had to look up “wan” for proper definition, wan : pale & weak (of a person's complexion or appearance) pale and giving the impression of illness or exhaustion. So that’s what English translation here is saying I think.