# What is the relation between Niti , Nyaya and Dharma?

Tags: dharma, terminology, nyaya

- Ruling Lands of great Kings are said to be complete in Niti , Nyaya and Dharma without any decline.
- While solving problems, these three must be there in judgement and one must only live considering these three.(A common Saying in South)

**MY QUESTION :**

- What is the relation between Niti , Nyaya and Dharma ?
- Why these three are always said together ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/what-is-difference-between-neeti-and-dharma

Comment: @SwiftPushkar that is difference between Niti and Dharma, this question is about the realtion between Nyay,Niti and Dharma.