# Was Dhrishtadyumna the rebirth of Ekalavya to take revenge on Dronacharya?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

I heard in a video Ekalavya was killed by Lord Krishna and at that time Lord Krishna gave a boon. i
e. rebirth as Dhrishtadyumna to take revenge on Dronacharya. Is that true?

Comment: Can you pl mention where did you read that @Deadpool ?

Comment: in this video at 7th minute https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDBn7FOzsko

Comment: Seems less possibility..Eklavya was incarnation from Asura class called Krodhavasa however Dhrishtadyumna was portion of Agni..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Mahabharata, Adi Parva, SECTION LXVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm), Dhrishtadyumna was incarnated from the portion of Agni.

> "Know also, O monarch, that the mighty car-warrior Dhrishtadyumna was a portion of Agni.

And Ekalavya was incarnated from the portion of Asura called Krodhavasa.

> Madraka, and Karnaveshta, Siddhartha, and also Kitaka; Suvira, and Suvahu, and Mahavira, and also Valhika, Kratha, Vichitra, Suratha, and the handsome king Nila; and Chiravasa, and Bhumipala; and Dantavakra, and he who was called Durjaya; that tiger amongst kings named Rukmi; and king Janamejaya, Ashada, and Vayuvega, and also Bhuritejas; **Ekalavya**, and Sumitra, Vatadhana, and also Gomukha; the tribe of kings called the Karushakas, and also Khemadhurti; Srutayu, and Udvaha, and also Vrihatsena; Kshema, Ugratirtha, the king of the Kalingas; and Matimat, and he was known as king Iswara; **these first of kings were all born of the Asura class called Krodhavasa**.

Comment: i know he born from agni because of pooja or yagam done by his father by maltreating some rishi's

Comment: You can add this too "Ekalavya was born of the Asura class called Krodhavasa". ~ https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28269/12304