# Can Vishnu's multiple avatars exist at the same time on earth?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars

I thought Vishnu takes an avatar to remove adharma from our planet yet two avatars of Vishnu can exist at the same time on earth? Why is there a need for two avatars at the same time? Parashu Rama and Krishna existed in the same time frame right or am I wrong? Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu it seems u hv added few Qs unnecessarily in the original Q..

Comment: I did not know exactly what he was asking but he is free to correct it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu - Somebody had edited my question but my question was primarily about  whether multiple avatars of God Vishnu can exist at the same time ...

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi As far as I know the topic starter (and mods) is always the one who can accept or reject suggestions to edit the question.

Comment: Although my answer was deleted I can say from my experience that only one Avatar of Vishnu comes in Universe at one time. Krishna said he is the only God and during the times of Rama people said Ram is the only king.

Comment: @DheerajVerma this abviously not true since Parashurama was also alive during the time of Rama and Krishna.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu There is some misinterpretation I think. People did not pray to Parshuram as avatar of Vishnu during the times of Ramayan or Mahabharata. If Parshuram was all capable Vishnu then what was the need for Ram during Ramayana? He was great and someone made him a God when he was not. I doubt those texts which claim Parshuram was a avatar of Vishnu and was present simultaneously with Ram and Krishna.

Comment: "If Parshuram was all capable Vishnu then what was the need for Ram during Ramayana? " Yes! This is a question which I was going to ask. Parshurama is however not a full incarnation of Vishnu maybe that also plays a role. He has been named in numerous texts and is part of the dashavatara;  I do not doubt the existence of Parshuram as avatar of Vishnu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Lord Vishnu's multiple avatars can exist at the same time on earth.

For example,

- Lord Parashurama and Lord Rama were present at the same time (~**Valmiki Ramayana: Balakanda: [Sarga74](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga74/bala_74_frame.htm)-76**)
- Lord Parashurama and Lord Krishna were present at the same time (~**Mahabharata: Udyoga Parva: Bhagwat Yana Parva: Section [XCVI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05096.htm)**)
- Lord Krishna and Lord Vyasa were present at the same time (~**Mahabharata: Sauptika Parva: Section [XIV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10014.htm)**)

Apart from these instances, [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/23) consider both Lord Balarāma and Lord Krishna as incarnations of Lord Vishnu (From 4 forms of Lord Vishnu: Vāsudeva, Saṅkarṣaṇa, Aniruddha and Pradyumna; Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa is Vāsudeva, and Baladeva is Saṅkarṣaṇa). And it's well known that Lord Balarāma and Lord Krishna performed many activities together since their childhood.

Comment: Just a quick query. Wasn't Balarama said to be Sheshnag? But perhaps you might mean Sankarshana which is an expansion of Vishnu itself?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar The [link](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/23) mentioned in the answer clarifies this..

Comment: so it is Sankarshana.