# How can Yuddhistirha be son of Yamraj ji if Yamraj Ji himself incarnated as Vidura

Tags: pandavas, yudhisthira, yama, vidura, mahabharata

I have recently learned that Vidura Ji is the incarnation of Yamraj ji because of the curse given by Rishi Mandavya. But it is known that Pandu and Kunti ask Yamraj ji for a son (Yuddhistira).So I am confused How is it possible?

Comment: devas bodies are not like human bodies. they can be in multiple places and multiple forms at same time. if yama takes avatar as vidura, it doesn't mean he cannot grant boon to kunti for a son.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Vishnu's multiple avatars exist at the same time on earth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/can-vishnus-multiple-avatars-exist-at-the-same-time-on-earth) and [Are the Pandavas the sons of Gods, or Gods themselves?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/41062/12304)