# What is the connection between Vidura from Mahabharata & Rishi Atri?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, rishi, yama, vidura

**[Mahabharat Sambhava Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm)** mentions the following about Vidura:

> O king, thou shouldst know that he who was known on earth as Vidura, who was the first of all virtuous men, who was the god of Justice himself, was the excellent and greatly fortunate son of the Rishi Atri.

I know Vidura is believed to have been a portion of Dharmaraja and that Rishi Atri had three sons - Soma/Chandra, Dattatreya and Durvasa rishi. Am not sure how Vidura or Dharma connects to either of them and my question is - **What is their connection to Rishi Atri?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems translation issue. Instead of saying son of Surya, it says son of Atri.

In SanskritDocuments, I found two equivalent Sanskrit Shlokas for this:

> dharmAttu sumahAbhAgaM putraM putravatAM varam .
>
> viduraM viddhi taM loke jAtaM buddhimatAM varam ..  ~ [sanskritdocuments 1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/txt/mbhK01.itx)

For this Sanskrit Shloka, there is no need to mention Atri in the translation. It clearly says he was incarnation of Dharma.

But another verion has the word Atri in it and it seems this translation has used this shloka:

> atrestu sumahAbhAgaM putraM putravatAM varam |
>
> viduraM viddhi loke.asmi~njAtaM buddhimatAM varam || ~ [sanskritdocuments 2](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh01.itx)

This is how it is translated in Sanskrit-Hindi version of Mahabharat by Gitapress Gorakhpur:

> [image: Vidura was incarnation of Suryaputra Dharama]

So *atrestu* is translated as Surya Putra.

[Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm) says

> the illustrious Atri who illumined the world of old when the Sun was lost..

So may be Atri is derived from one of the Surya's name as he illumined the world of old when the Sun was lost. I would add it's reference if Atri was Surya's name too if found somewhere.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a possibility. Do add the reference to that then I can select this as the right answer.