# Can asuras be born as humans like how devas are born as avadhutas

Tags: gods, asuras, vedic-gods, demi-god, devatas

Do asuras have the power to manifest as humans like how hanuman is a manifestation of shiva.

Comment: There are many instances you can find in Itihasa. For example Putana Rakshasi came to Krishna as a beautiful woman to feed him poisonous milk.

Comment: See https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

Comment: many asuras incarnated as humans in MBH, see [What were the previous births of the characters of Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7039/12304)

Comment: The whole reason for Krishna avatar was this only.

Comment: the jivas that are asuras - like the jivas in humans - are temporary. When the karma that made them asuras wears out, they will have to take rebirth based on their existing karma. All jivas must be born as humans to attain moksha.

Comment: yes, in kali yuga, some rakshasa/asuras take birth as brahmins