# Is Arjun, the incarnation of Lord Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, krishna, mahabharata

Some people claim that Arjun is the incarnation of Lord Vishnu. But is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Mahabharata: Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva: Chapter 12](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03012.htm), Lord Krishna himself says:

> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Having addressed Krishna thus, the illustrious Pandava, who was the soul of Krishna, became dumb, when Janardana (in reply addressed that son of Pritha) saying, 'Thou art mine and I am thine, while all that is mine is thine also! He that hateth thee hateth me as well, and he that followeth thee followeth me! **O thou irrepressible one, thou art Nara and I am Narayana or Hari! We are the Rishis Nara and Narayana born in the world of men for a special purpose. O Partha, thou art from me and I am from thee! O bull of the Bharata race, no one can understand the difference that is between us!**'

---

Nara-Nārāyaṇa are considered incarnations of Lord Vishnu:

- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Skandha 12: The Age of Deterioration: CHAPTER EIGHT: Mārkaṇḍeya’s Prayers to Nara-Nārāyaṇa Ṛṣi](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/8/)

  > Text 35:
  > These two sages, Nara and Nārāyaṇa, were the direct personal forms of the Supreme Lord.
- In [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Skandha 11: General History
  CHAPTER FOUR: Drumila Explains the Incarnations of Godhead to King Nimi](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/4/), Nara-Nārāyaṇa is listed as incarnation along with other incarnations such as Hayagrīva, Nṛsiṁha, Vāmana, Paraśurāma, Rāmacandra, Krishna, Buddha, and Kalki etc.

---

Thus, Arjuna is the incarnation of Lord Vishnu (Vishnu --> Nara --> Arjuna). On a side note, Arjuna is also considered incarnation/son of Indra ([What were the previous births of the characters of Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/what-were-the-previous-births-of-the-characters-of-mahabharata/28269#28269)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Arjuna is an incarnation of Rishi Nara, who was an incarnation of Lord Vishnu -

> "He is even a Rishi of great energy, the friend of Narayana; ancient,
> eternal a god himself, invincible, ever successful, and knowing no
> deterioration"

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7311.html

> "You were in your former life Nara, the friend of Narayana. In Vadari
> were you engaged in fierce ascetic austerities for several thousands
> of years. In you as well as in Vishnu—that first of male beings—dwells
> great might. You both, by your might, hold the universe; O lord,
> taking up that fierce bow whose twang resembled the deep roar of the
> clouds, you, as well as Krishna, chastisedest the Danavas during the
> coronation of Indra. Even this Gandiva is that bow, O son of Pritha,
> fit for your hands".

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7316.html

> "Those ancient and excellent Rishis who were known by the names of
> Nara and Narayana are, know, O Brahmana, none else than Hrishikesa and
> Dhananjaya."

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7324.html

2. Nara and Narayana are all powerful

> 'Without doubt, O Suta’s son, it is Time that destroyes the universe.
> And it is Time that again creates everything. Nothing here is eternal.
> It is Nara and Narayana, endued with omniscience, that destroyes all
> creatures.[2] The gods speak of him as Vaikuntha (of immeasurable
> puissance), while men call him Vishnu (one that pervades the
> Universe)!'"

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375155.html